# Facebook Zapier parser XML feed

Tags: xml, facebook, parsing, zapier

I would like to have a code that can interpret an XML file and convert it to line-items in a CSV or XML file to sync it back to Facebook.
Facebook has a list of required fields that don't match with the ones located in my XML file.
Therefore I am keen to format the data from the feed so it can match Facebook's requirements.
The XML file is located in a URL and refreshed daily to reflect the changes in the vehicle stock.
Here is the solution provided by Zapier, you will see the missing part of the puzzle in bold.
Can you please help me in this process?

Advice from Zapier:

> You're setting up a feed that always uploads a file from the same URL, so you would need a way to update the file at that location. The way I can think about doing that with Zapier would be:
>   Trigger: Email App: New Attachment
>   Action: Filter: Check if it's an XML file and continue if it is.
>   Action: Dropbox: Upload File (to read the file's text as a value)
>   Action: Code by Zapier: Your custom code to interpret the XML file and convert it to line-items (**this part is outside our scope of support, but if you need help you can ask on Stack Overflow. Tag your question with "Zapier" and there are usually folks willing to help out)**
>   Action: Google Sheets: Create or Update Spreadsheet Row(s)
>
> You would need to have the Google Sheet "published" to the web as a CSV or XML file. This link is really long so it's extremely unlikely anyone would be able to find it and see the current data. The URL won't change, so you would be able to use it as your feed to Facebook Dynamic Ads. The "published" version will be updated every 5 minutes or less from the Google Sheet you would be updating.
>
> I think being able to Parse XML into its separate values would be a useful addition to our Formatter app. I've created a feature request for this and we'll notify you by email if it gets implemented. In theory, it could alleviate the need for custom code here.